# Quitar archivos añadidos antes de un commit

Tags: git

Por error añadí unos archivos que no quería agregar a un `commit`, hice esto:

```
git add .
```

La cuestión es que eso añadió todos los archivos en la carpeta y hay un par de archivos que no quería commitear porque eran para mis tests.

Cuando hago esto:

```
git status
```

Obtengo:

```
archivo1.js
archivo2.js
archivoQueNoQuieroCommitear.js
```

**Pregunta**

Dado que no he hecho `commit` ¿cómo quito `archivoQueNoQuieroCommitear.js` del commit?

De ser posible estoy intentando resetear el head.

Los archivos no existían antes así que no les puedo hacer `checkout`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Debes removerlos del index con:

```
git reset <paths>
```

Tomado de la [documentación](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#_description):

> ***`git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>…​`***
>
> Esta forma restablece las entradas del "index" para todos los `<paths>` a su correspondiente estado en `<tree-ish>` (Esto no affecta el "working tree" ni el "branch" actual).
>
> Esto quiere decir que `git reset <paths>` es lo opuesto a `git add <paths>`

Para que entiendas mejor que sucede, lo que el comando `git add` hace, es agregar una entrada al "index" con el contenido actual del archivo en el "working tree" (tu directorio de trabajo).

Cuando digo agregar una entrada al "index", me refiero a que `git add` hace una copia de tu archivo de trabajo (el que editaste) a una "zona" conocida como *staging* (es una carpeta dentro de el directorio `.git`), desde donde toma los archivos el comando `git commit`.

Esto son archivos nuevos así que están únicamente el working tree y en el index, pero no en el branch actual, por lo que no tienen HEAD así que no podrás obtenerlos de ahí.

`git reset` elimina el/los archivos del "index" y solo quedara el original en tu working tree. Que es lo que querías.

Comment: @Darkhogg Creo que estas equivocado, "index" es parte de la jerga de git, por eso intento explicarlo luego, para que se entienda de que se esta hablando.

Comment: @Darkhogg La palabra *index* es una palabra del Latín Clásico, y originalmente nombra al dedo índice, y por extensión significa apuntar, señalar. De ahí tenemos *index librorum prohibitorum*, o índice de libros prohibidos de la Iglesia Católica. También la usamos en el *índice de un libro*. El Castellano, como otras lenguas Romances, deriva del Latín, y la palabra es aceptada por la RAE en sus formas índex e índice.

Answer (score 4):

Para revertir específicamente `git add`, se realiza con:

```
git reset <archivo>
```

[**Documentación**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) (inglés):

> `git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>…​` : Esta forma restablece las entradas del "index" para todos los 
>   a su correspondiente estado en  (Esto no affecta el "working
>   tree" ni el "branch" actual).

De hecho veo que es una pregunta muy vista en stackoverflow:

**[Revertir 'git add' antes de un commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add-before-commit) (inglés).**

Comment: Creo que git reset quita todo lo que añadiste.

Comment: @WilfredoP! eso lo deje por error, lo acabo de quitar!

Comment: @Elenasys interesante lo de que sea una pregunta muy vista, no supe cómo buscarlo en primer lugar y mis intentos de guglearlo fueron fallidos.

Comment: Pues únicamente con "git add undo before commit", regularmente busco más información para estar al día, me pareció interesante el uso de "git reset" sin parámetros, "cuando no se tiene ningún commit en su historial, pero da un índice vacío".

Comment: @Elenasys iba a probar lo de git reset sin parámetros pero me da miedo arruinar mi repositorio y justo ahora estoy trabajando en contra del tiempo. Lo probaré luego con un repositorio de prueba.

Comment: @WilfredoP muy peligroso hacer experimentos con el deadline cerca! haha!, cuando lo pruebes nos comentas que concluyes!, saludos.

Answer (score 4):

```
git reset ruta [nombre del archivo]
```

Si el archivo esta en el directorio actual

```
git reset [archivo a ignorar]
```

Si el archivo esta en una ruta diferente al directorio actual

```
git reset [ruta/nombre archivo a ignorar]
```

Answer (score 3):

Con `git reset <archivo>` reviertes el archivo que añadiste con `git add .` antes un commit.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que no seria bueno usar un git reset, ya que estos son para eliminar commits o retroceder a un commit especifico.

Si quieres quitar un archivo del index(listado de archivos a los que se les añadio con add pero no se les realizó commit) es mejor usar git rm:

```
git rm --cached ruta-de-archivo
```